# Java OpenCV - how to make BufferedImage from Mat directly

Tags: java, opencv, bufferedimage

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
      System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
      VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture(0);
      Mat m = new Mat(5,5, 0);
      vc.retrieve(m);
  }
```

How can i get BufferedImage from this mat. Is it possible? If not please suggest me some other methode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
public static BufferedImage mat2Img(Mat in)
{
    BufferedImage out;
    byte[] data = new byte[320 * 240 * (int)in.elemSize()];
    int type;
    in.get(0, 0, data);

    if(in.channels() == 1)
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    else
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;

    out = new BufferedImage(320, 240, type);

    out.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, 320, 240, data);
    return out;
}
```

[reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/752511/How-to-Convert-Mat-to-BufferedImage-Vice-Versa)

Comment: @gmk is your `Mat` GRAY or RGB?

Comment: if your `Mat` is GARY, you will get a GRAY out from this method.

Comment: Mat webcam_image = new Mat();  
         VideoCapture webCam = new VideoCapture(0);

Comment: Dispaly your `webcam_image`, see if it's GRAY or RGB.